# Odd Performance (Boxed Integers)

Tags: java, performance, optimization, jit

I've run into a case where I thought the JIT should have an easy time optimising, but it does not seem to.

I've reduced the problem to a minimal example:

Consider a class `IntArrayWrapper`:

```
class IntArrayWrapper {
    private int[] data = new int[100000];
    public void setInteger(int i, Integer x) { data[i] = x; }
    public void setInt    (int i, int x)     { data[i] = x; }
}
```

The only difference between the two methods is that `x` is an `Integer` (boxed) or an `int` (primitive).

I've written some JMH benchmarks to measure the performance of these two methods:

```
@Benchmark
public void bmarkSetIntConst() {
    final IntArrayWrapper w = new IntArrayWrapper();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        w.setInt(i, 100);
    }
}

@Benchmark
public void bmarkSetIntStair() {
    final IntArrayWrapper w = new IntArrayWrapper();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        w.setInt(i, i);
    }
}

// omitted: bmarkSetIntegerConst and bmarkSetIntStair that use .setInteger(..)
```

## Expected Results

What I expected to see was:

- `setIntegerConst` equal to `setIntConst`. **THIS IS TRUE.**
- `setIntegerStair` equal to `setIntStair`. **THIS IS NOT TRUE.**

The reason I thought was that I think that the JIT should inline the `setInteger` call, and realise that there is an auto-boxing operation (from the call) directly followed by an unboxing operation (from the array assignment) and therefore be able to remove the boxing/unboxing.

This does *not* seem to be the case.

#### Some observations

- The const operations perform equally well, I think this is due to the fact that the hard-coded integer is cached.
- It's strange that `setIntStair` and `setIntConst` have different performance, I have a feeling that the JIT might produce SIMD code here, but I'd be grateful for any insights.

## Results

These are the results, the whole code is here: https://gist.github.com/kaeluka/fe1210074038424c30db7a52ac5c2d7b

```
Benchmark                             Mode  Cnt      Score     Error  Units
MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntConst         thrpt   20  15717.814 ± 362.137  ops/s
MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntegerConst     thrpt   20  15814.296 ± 657.945  ops/s
MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntStair         thrpt   20  11941.879 ± 200.335  ops/s
MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntegerStair     thrpt   20   2981.398 ±  48.806  ops/s
MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntSawtooth      thrpt   20  11072.882 ± 234.686  ops/s
MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntegerSawtooth  thrpt   20  11105.272 ± 156.496  ops/s
```

## Questions

- Why is the JIT not able to elide boxing?
- Is there a way to fix this *without* changing the interface of `setInteger` to take an `int`? (My original code uses generics, so `int` is not an option unless I want to duplicate a lot of code).

#### Edits

Added results for `bmarkSetIntegerSawtooth` and `bmarkSetIntSawtooth` that set the value to `i % 128` to measure the impact of object pooling for `Integer`s.

Comment: How many warmup iterations does JMH do by default? Have you tried tweaking this value?

Comment: I wouldn't expect `setIntegerStair` to be equal to `setIntStair`. Your code is going to create a lot of different `Integer` not cached in the range -128, 127

Comment: The results are the same, even with smaller warmup iterations. The default is 20.

Comment: @Klaimmore I think that's the point--OP is wondering why the boxing isn't being elided entirely given that `setInteger` ought to be fully inlined.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Java does some constant pooling for `Integers` in the range mentioned by @Klaimmore. Could you re-run the tests, but modifying the stairs by  `setInteger(i, i % 128)`?

Comment: @Klaimmore: yes, what Mike says: I'd have expected there to be no objects at all.

Comment: what happens when you execute it with `-XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInlining` ?

Comment: I have considered constant pooling as a factor. It doesn't seem to be a factor here (the `Const` methods are equally slow even with the constant `1000`, for example). I believe that this is because the constant here is a compile-time constant which ends up being in the class' constant pool, regardless of the specific value. Great point, though!

Comment: @Turing85 I've added the `bmarkSetInt(eger)Sawtooth` benchmarks that do that. The performance of the `int` and the `Integer` version is equal.

Comment: @Klaimmore I've added the flags, but unfortunately can't make much of the output. This is the output for the `Stair` benchmarks: https://gist.github.com/kaeluka/26881b66ebcd20ce0c168ca9c9528028

Comment: @StephanBrandauer when I set the constant for the constant tests to `1000`, I get an annamoly: `MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntConst             
          thrpt   20  4488.890 ±  872.817  ops/s` vs. `MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntegerConst         thrpt   20  7486.776 ± 5879.997  ops/s` (`Integer` has almost 2x the throughput of `int`). Can you verify this behaviour?

Comment: @Turing85 wow, this is strange! For me, they have exactly the same performance:


`MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntConst      thrpt   20  16055.149 ± 434.838  ops/s` vs.
`MyBenchmark.bmarkSetIntegerConst  thrpt   20  16038.776 ± 604.971  ops/s`

Comment: @StephanBrandauer results get weird for me when I set warmup- and measurement-iterations to `1000`... you can look at the data [here](https://pastebin.com/TjW8LkRb)

Comment: I can't tell you *why* it's not eliding the boxing.  If I had to guess, the possibility of indexing into the `Integer` cache may be throwing it off. 
 Looking at the disassembly, it does indeed look like everything is being inlined, including the (un)boxing methods.  Changing the `Integer` cache size may close the performance gap, but it won't fix the fundamental fact that the JIT doesn't seem capable of eliding the boxing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the JIT not able to elide boxing?

I would guess that the JIT does not *specifically* target boxing operations, but relies on regular escape analysis to eliminate unnecessary boxing.  Escape analysis is rather picky about data flow, and I suspect the problem is that *some* of your boxing operations hit the `Integer` cache.  Potentially pulling values out of the cache is probably what's preventing the boxing from being eliminated.

I've modified your test in two ways, and measured the results of each.  The results seem to confirm my hypothesis.

1. I first tried rewriting your benchmarks to use boxed `double` values instead of `int` values, as `double` boxing does not involve any caching.
2. I then went back to the `int`-based benchmarks, but modified your loops to start at `i = 128` so that none of your boxing operations ever hit the cache.

In both cases, the performance gap closed to within the margin of error.

To confirm, I enabled `-XX:+PrintAssembly` to see how my modified benchmarks were getting compiled.  For each pair of benchmarks, the boxing and primitive variants had nearly identical instruction sequences.  There were only minor differences, e.g., a pair of instructions flipped.  It definitely looked like the boxing was optimized away.

**Workaround:** Since bypassing the cache seems to avoid the issue, and there is no way force an empty integer cache, one workaround would be to replace implicit boxing with `new Integer(i)`.  Note, however, that if escape analysis **doesn't** replace the allocations (due to hitting one of the various compiler thresholds), then your performance may actually **degrade**.

---

Modified Benchmarks:

```
class IntArrayWrapper {
    private int[] data = new int[100000];
    void setBoxed(int i, Integer x) { data[i] = x; }
    void setUnboxed(int i, int x) { data[i] = x; }
}

class DoubleArrayWrapper {
    private double[] data = new double[100000];
    void setBoxed(int i, Double x) { data[i] = x; }
    void setUnboxed(int i, double x) { data[i] = x; }
}

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class BoxingBenchmarks {
    @Benchmark
    public void intBoxed() {
        final IntArrayWrapper w = new IntArrayWrapper();
        for (int i = 128; i < 100000; i++) w.setBoxed(i, i);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void intUnboxed() {
        final IntArrayWrapper w = new IntArrayWrapper();
        for (int i = 128; i < 100000; i++) w.setUnboxed(i, i);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void doubleBoxed() {
        final DoubleArrayWrapper w = new DoubleArrayWrapper();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) w.setBoxed(i, (double) i);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void doubleUnboxed() {
        final DoubleArrayWrapper w = new DoubleArrayWrapper();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) w.setUnboxed(i, (double) i);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Benchmark                        Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
BoxingBenchmarks.doubleBoxed    thrpt    5   6513.760 ± 1075.605  ops/s
BoxingBenchmarks.doubleUnboxed  thrpt    5   6883.235 ±  414.803  ops/s
BoxingBenchmarks.intBoxed       thrpt    5  10902.200 ±  315.437  ops/s
BoxingBenchmarks.intUnboxed     thrpt    5  11148.648 ±  935.877  ops/s
```

Comment: Wow, that's a **great** insight. I don't know yet whether that helps me, but I now know a work-around!

Modifying the benchmark to pass `new Integer(i)` closes the preformance gap on my computer! If you can a) confirm that and b) edit your answer to include the solution, I'll happily accept your answer.

Thank you!

Alternatively, you could, I suppose, modify the Integer class using XBootClasspath to remove caching, but that's too magical for my use case.

Comment: Replacing implicit boxing with `new Integer` will enable the _possibility_ of the boxing being elided.  Whether that actually happens depends on several factors, including (1) whether the callee gets inlined, and (2) whether the escape analysis thresholds been exceeded when your call site is analyzed.  In other words, what you suggest may work, but in some cases your performance may actually degrade.